# How to delete duplicate LiDAR points?

Tags: point, lidar, duplication, remove

How can I delete duplicate LiDAR points? I incorrectly read the same las twice and saved as a one file resulting in duplicate XY points.  How should I delete these duplicate points?

Comment: What software and/or tools are you using and what format is your data in (.las for example)? In ArcGIS there's a Delete Identical tool at the Advanced License level... but I don't know if that would work on a LIDAR point cloud.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete all duplicate points from a las, laz or ascii file using  [`lasduplicate`](http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasduplicate/) in LAStools.

> Finds and removes all duplicate points from a LAS/LAZ/ASCII file. In
>   the default mode those are xy-duplicate points that have identical x
>   and y coordinates. The first point survives, all subsequent duplicates
>   are removed. It is also possible to keep the lowest points amongst all
>   xy-duplicates via ‘-lowest_z’.
>
> It is also possible to remove only xyz-duplicates points that have all
>   x, y and z coordinates identical via ‘-unique_xyz’.

Also, `lasfilterduplicates` in the [lidR package (documentation p. 51)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf):

```
lasfilterduplicates(las)
```

> Filter points that appear more than once in the point cloud according
>   to their X Y Z coordinates

Answer (score 1):

If you consider to remove duplicated points on X, Y coordinates (with different Z), after using `lasfilterduplicates` function from `lidR` package, you may use `lasfilter` function.

```
las <- lasfilter(las, !duplicated(las@data, by = c("X", "Y")))
```

I think it will retain the first return points (from that duplicated points).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a tool in WhiteboxTools - LidarRemoveDuplicates. You can run it separately through CMD line or as QGIS 3.4 plugin. Instruction on how to use and install WhiteboxTools in on their [webpage](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

As an update on the answers by @wnursal and @Aaron :

The `lidR` package function `lasfilterduplicates()` is deprecated.
Instead, you can use the maintained version `filter_duplicates()`. This can be applied to LAS files and LAS catalog objects.

When loading a catalog or a file, you can already set this within the function, and this maybe works also in your case:

```
# catalog
ctg <- lidR::readLAScatalog("path/to/folder", filter = "-drop_overlap")
```

---

More options on filtering the initial data with `readLAS(filter = "-help")`, not to be confused with later filtering based on Boolean criteria with `filter_poi()`